# I am trying to click on a button on webpage which is an image using VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to click a button on webpage which does not have any text, its just a small submit image, which is used for submission.
Below are the details i get when i click on inspect element.

```html
<td style="text-align: center">
<img class="edit" style="cursor:pointer" 
  src="/slakpi/Images/edit_icon.png" onclick="editRow(this,17235)"></td>
```

Thanks in advance :)

My VBA code is as following.

```vb
Sub SIM() 
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer 
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
    Dim y As Integer 
    Dim reslt As String 
    Dim objCollection As Object 
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = True 
    ie.navigate "https://....navigae to some site" 
    Do 
        DoEvents 
    Loop Until 
    ie.readyState = 4 
    Set allhyperlink = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A") 
    For Each hyper_link In allhyperlink 
        If hyper_link.innerText = "Worklist" Then 
            hyper_link.Click 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next 'clicking on image submit button 
    Set cvabutton = doc.getElementsByClassName("edit")(1) 
    cvabutton.Click 
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the details.

Comment: Welcome to the community @johg6

Comment: Hi Roy, Please Let me know what details are requires.

Comment: <td style="text-align: center"><img class="edit" style="cursor:pointer" src="/slakpi/Images/edit_icon.png" onclick="editRow(this,17235)"></td>

Comment: Details like what is the issue you are facing, What code you have written so far. The above html snippet helps but those details are also required to understand the issue. Please edit the question and update those details

Comment: I am very new to VBA, i have coded using element id or name, but here i am unable to find any such identifier.

Comment: You can try to locate using `class` name here. In case there are multiple items with class name as `edit` we can use `xpath`.

Comment: i tried this code. objie.document.querySelector("img[class*= edit]").Click        , but its not clicking on the button

Comment: I am assuming you are using HTTP request to get the DOM and from there you are trying to parse the page. `document.querySelector` accepts CSS selector not xpath. This is the reason I asked earlier `What code you have written so far`. For an `img` element with class `edit` css selector would be `img.edit`. To learn more about CSS selector refer https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Sub SIM()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
Dim y As Integer
Dim reslt As String
Dim objCollection As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://....navigae to some site"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

Set allhyperlink = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A")

For Each hyper_link In allhyperlink
If hyper_link.innerText = "Worklist" Then
hyper_link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
'clicking on image submit button
Set cvabutton = doc.getElementsByClassName("edit")(1)
cvabutton.Click
End Sub

Comment: It's very difficult to read code from the comment since it is not formatted. I have updated the code in your question body. If it is the same as your code, kindly confirm.

Comment: However i belive problem lies at the line `Set cvabutton = doc.getElementsByClassName("edit")(1) `. `doc` is undefined.

Comment: Yes Roy, error is in that line. I have never worked with Img Class, hence tried with the class element but its throwing error. i tried defining cvabutton as Object still no result

Comment: As I Mentioned `doc` is not defined. Therefore it is throwing error. Try `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("edit")(1)`. It should be resolved.

Comment: I am very rookie to this. i am still getting error of 'Object variable or With block variable not set'    Code : Set cvabutton = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("edit")(1)
cvabutton.Click

Comment: Please update your question with the actual URLs that you are hitting. Otherwise, it is not possible to debug from our end

Comment: Finally its working now, i had to add some wait time.   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:4"))